# cPickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated

Tags: python, sockets, django-models, rpc, pickle

i use a Remote Procedure call to communicate between two prozesses. I send objects from the on hand to the other. the object is a object by a django model. The object has different variables, integers and strings.

If i change only integer variables everything works fine. if i change a string variable in the first time it works, too but if i change a string second time my code crashes and i get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manch011/disserver/src/disserver/gui/backends/receiver.py", line 69, in run
    name, args, kwargs = cPickle.load(connFile)
cPickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

This is my code,
on the server-side:

```
_exportedMethods = {
    'changes': signal_when_changes,
}  

class ServerThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ServerThread,self).__init__()
        st = self
    #threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        HOST = ''     # local host
        PORT = 50000
        SERVER_ADDRESS = HOST, PORT

        # set up server socket
        s = socket.socket()
        s.bind(SERVER_ADDRESS)
        s.listen(5)

        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            connFile = conn.makefile()
            name, args, kwargs = cPickle.load(connFile)
            res = _exportedMethods[name](*args,**kwargs)
            cPickle.dump(res,connFile) ; connFile.flush()
            conn.close()
```

And this is the client-side:

```
class RemoteFunction(object):
def __init__(self,serverAddress,name):
    self.serverAddress = serverAddress
    self.name = name
def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(self.serverAddress)
    f = s.makefile()
    cPickle.dump((self.name,args,kwargs), f) 
    f.flush()
    res = cPickle.load(f)
    s.close()
    return res

def machine_changed_signal(machine):
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 50000
    SERVER_ADDRESS = HOST, PORT
    advise = RemoteFunction(SERVER_ADDRESS,'changes')
    advise(machine)
```

I am not familiar with cPickle and hence cannot figure this one out, can someone explain it to me?

Thanks in advance Chis

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem. But first the error message I describe in my question is not meaningful.

I am the problem tackled new and have used the Pyro4 Framework. So i got a new error message which was equivalent to the old but clearly. U cant pickle class objects. 
Because I need in my case only the attribute values ​​I pass this in a simple dictionary.

At first download [Pyro4](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4/) and install it
A simple example similar to the example on the [Pyro homepage](http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/intro.html):

```
# saved as helloworld.py
import Pyro4
import threading
import os
class HelloWorld(object):
    def get_hello_world(self, name):
        return "HelloWorld,{0}.".format(name)

#The NameServer had to run in a own thread because he has his own eventloop
class NameServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
    os.system("python -m Pyro4.naming")
ns = NameServer()
ns.start()
hello_world=HelloWorld()
daemon=Pyro4.Daemon()                 # make a Pyro daemon
ns=Pyro4.locateNS()                   # find the name server
uri=daemon.register(hello_world)   # register the greeting object as a Pyro object
ns.register("example.helloworld", uri)  # register the object with a name in the name server
print "Ready."
daemon.requestLoop()                  # start the event loop of the server to wait for calls
```

run this programm and execute the next after

```
# saved as client.py
import Pyro4
name=raw_input("What is your name? ").strip()
helloworld=Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:example.helloworld")    # use name server object lookup uri shortcut
print helloworld.get_hello_world(name)
```

Important u cant transfer class instances. So "name" could not be a class instance.

Comment: Could you add some code, or an example of how you solved your problem? If the link goes down, or dies, there's no information in this post that will help future viewers.

Comment: Yep, that's all I was after - I don't personally need it, but other people might, and that'll be much more helpful. Thanks for posting it so quickly. :)